# Customizing the appearance of a JMenuBar

Tags: java, swing, jmenubar

How can I change the default look of a JMenuBar, JMenuItem, etc.? For example, how could I change it to look more like Photoshop's menu bar?

This is my code for the file menu class:

```
package com.digitaloutlet.gui;

import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;

public class FileMenu {
  public static void FileMenu() {
    JMenuBar menubar;
    JMenu file;
    JMenuItem menuItem, open;

    menubar = new JMenuBar();

    file = new JMenu("File");

    menuItem = new JMenuItem("New");
    open = new JMenuItem("Open");


    menubar.add(file);
    file.add(menuItem);
    file.add(open);

    Window.frame.setJMenuBar(menubar);
  }
}
```

If you need more info, please let me know.

Comment: [Modifying the Look and Feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/index.html)

Comment: Please don't add your tags to your title. You already added your tags to your tags.

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly remember what the Photoshop menu bar looks like, but I find that it looks quite neat without a border. You can use the code below to get rid of the border.

```
menubar.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
```